# Same folder routing different views React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I currently have a view that contains a button from which I would like to link it to the details view.

My solution folder looks like:

```
/views
 /logging
  index.js
  loggingdetails.js
```

And this is my App router:

```
import Logging from './views/logging';
import LoggingDetail from './views/logging/LoggingDetail.js';
class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Reboot />
                <Router history={this.props.history}>
                    <div id="router">
                        <Switch>
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/logging" component={ Logging } layout={ MainLayout }/>
                            <AuthenticatedRoute path="/logging/:id" component={ LoggingDetail } layout={ MainLayout }/>
                            <AuthenticatedRoute component={ Dashboard } layout={ MainLayout }/>
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I did not include some imports because they are irrelevant.

And this is my link in the index:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/logging'}}>Test</Link>
```

But whatever I just changes the URL but does not render LoggingDetails.js content.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Try adding `exact` to `/logging` or switching `/logging` and `/logging/:id`.

Comment: I did some changes and it worked as you said Oblosys...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the loginDetail component to be shown, you would need to be at an the address that has the id. 
“/logging/123” for example.  That will render both the Logging and LoggingDetail components. If you only want the LoginDetail render when there is an ID in the address bar, then change the path=“/logging” to be ‘exact path=“/logging”’. Then the Logging component will only show when the address is /logging and nothing after it.